# Merge two Columns when specific Column starts with a Specific test

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I need to change two columns in every line where "Color" column starts with a specific value "yell"

My table is:

```
+------+----------+----------+
| Name | Color    | Quantity |
+------+----------+----------+
| A    | <yell> U | 2        |
+------+----------+----------+
| B    | Blue     | 1        |
+------+----------+----------+
| C    | Red      | 4        |
+------+----------+----------+
| D    | <yell> A | 2        |
+------+----------+----------+
```

For this, example table, I have 2 lines where column Collor starts with the string "Yell" . I need to change that field to Yellow and Put quantity = quantity-1, for the column "Quantity"

I need to match only the first 6 characters of the Collor string . What comes after this can be different from line to line.

So my table would be:

```
+------+--------+----------+
| Name | Color  | Quantity |
+------+--------+----------+
| A    | Yellow | 1        |
+------+--------+----------+
| B    | Blue   | 1        |
+------+--------+----------+
| C    | Red    | 4        |
+------+--------+----------+
| D    | Yellow | 1        |
+------+--------+----------+
```

Can you help me? I've tried a merge but i'm not doing it right.

Comment: That just looks like a simple update query. Are you not telling us something?

Comment: Yah but I need to match only the (yell)  not the rest of the string

Comment: Where Color like '<yell>%'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
   update TABLENAME a
       set a.color = 'Yellow',
           a.quantity = a.quantity - 1
     where exists (select count(*)
              from TABLENAME t
             where substr(t.color, 1, 6) = substr(a.color, 1, 6)
             group by (substr(t.color, 1, 6))
            having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this =)

Comment: welcome, you can can modify update if you need more complex searches, instead of subsrt( 1, 6) you can use any condition or search pattern.

Comment: That where clause doesn't look right to me; where is the mention of `<yell>`? I would expect a where clause of something like `where substr(color, 1, 6) = '<yell>'` - maybe `lower()` needs to be applied around the substr, depending on the OP's data.

Comment: @Boneist I just gave a sample command as idea how to solve problem, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Seyran this doesn't work... It updates all the Colors to Yellow.. not only <yell>

Comment: update TABLENAME a
       set a.color = 'Yellow',
           a.quantity = a.quantity - 1
             where substr(t.color, 1, 6) = '<Yell>'

Comment: @UcanDoIt It updates only rows which have duplicate values in first 6 or less chars in Color column . I understood your question wrong, looking to your example i thought you need to update records which have duplicates, for your case you are right its just a simple update with where clause you specified .

Answer (score 0):

this actually requires only a straight forward update, at least as directly specified.

```
update tablename 
  set color = 'Yellow';
    , quantity = quantity-1
where substr(color,1,6) = '<yell>' ;
```

However, you may need to adjust the string in the where clause. As is it will update a color value 'some other stuff here', but will NOT update the value 'yellow' nor '', nor other variations.